# Apply a file to multiple folders using better PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, directory, scripting, subdirectory

I'm working on a project where I have to apply a file to multiple folders every so often.  I'm trying to learn some PowerShell commands to make this a little easier.  I came up with the following script, which works, but I feel that this is too verbose and could be distilled down with a better script:

```
[string]$sourceDirectory  = "C:\Setup\App Folder Files\*"
# Create an array of folders
$destinationDirectories = @(
'C:\Users\GG_RCB1\Documents\',
'C:\Users\GG_RCB2\Documents\',
'C:\Users\LA_RCB1\Documents\',
'C:\Users\PR_RCB1\Documents\',
'C:\Users\PQ_RCB1\Documents\',
'C:\Users\PQ_RCB2\Documents\',
'C:\Users\XC_RCB1\Documents\',
'C:\Users\XC_RCB2\Documents\',
'C:\Users\XC_RCB3\Documents\',
'C:\Users\XC_RCB4\Documents\',
'C:\Users\XC_RCB5\Documents\',
'C:\Users\XC_RCB6\Documents\',
'C:\Users\XC_RCB7\Documents\',
'C:\Users\XC_RCB8\Documents\')
# Perform iteration to create the same file in each folder
foreach ($i in $destinationDirectories) {
    Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $i
}
```

I go into this process knowing that every folder in the User folder area is going to have the same format:  _RCB<#>\Documents\

I know that I can loop through those files using this code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users'| where-object {$_.Name -match "^[A-Z][A-Z]_RCB"}
```

What I'm not sure how to do is to how, within that loop, drill down to the Documents folder and do the copy.  I want to avoid having to keep updating the array from the first code sample, particularly when I know the naming convention of the subfolders in the Users folder.  I'm just looking for a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You can pipe into `ForEach-Object` then use `Join-Path` to join `$_.FullName` with `Documents` and feed `Copy-Item -Destination`  this joined path

Comment: Or just do `foreach($i in Get-ChildItem C:\Users\[A-Z][A-Z]_*\Documents)` :)

Comment: Duh, forgot about the wildcards lol

Comment: Great suggestions !  I will try this out in the morning and confirm what worked.

Comment: The suggestion by Mathias was just what the doctor ordered.  The boiled down code is:  ```[string]$sourceDirectory  = "C:\Setup\App Folder Files\*"
foreach($i in Get-ChildItem C:\Users\[A-Z][A-Z]_RCB*\Documents)
{
    Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $i
} ```

Answer (score 2):

Ehh, I'll go ahead and post what I had in mind as well. Not to take away from [@Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) suggestion in the comments, but to offer my solution, here's my take:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\users\[A-Z][A-Z]_RCB*\documents" | 
    Copy-Item -Path $sourceDirectory -Destination { $_.FullName } -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Since everyone loves the "*One-Liners*" that can accomplish your needs. `Get-ChildItem` accepts *wildcard-expressions* in it's path which let's us accomplish this in one go. Given that your directories are...

1. consistent with the same naming pattern,

   - *[A-Z][A-Z]_**
2. and the folder destination is the same.

   - *Documents*

Luckily, `Copy-Item` also has some cool features on it's own such as being able to use a script block that will allow the passing of `$_.FullName` property as it's destination, while they are passed down the pipeline one at a time.

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` common parameter when you've dictated the results are what you're after*.

Comment: Thanks for your input Abraham.  I tested this and it worked just as well.  I also learned about the -WhatIf parameter - very handy for checking functionality